# Apache Royale Jewel How to use ScrollableSectionContent into ScrollableSectionContent?

Tags: scrollbar, apache-royale

I have something like this :

```
<j:initialView>
    <j:ResponsiveView>
        <j:ApplicationMainContent width="100%" selectedContent="ssc1">
            <j:ScrollableSectionContent name="ssc1" width="100%" /*also tried height="600"*/ >
                <j:Card height="600" width="200">
                    <j:Label text="A"/>
                    <j:Label text="B"/>
                    <j:ScrollableSectionContent width="100%" height="50">
                        <j:Label text="0"/>
                        <j:Label text="1"/>
                        <j:Label text="2"/>
                        <j:Label text="3"/>
                        <j:Label text="4"/>
                        <j:Label text="5"/>
                        </j:ScrollableSectionContent>
                    <j:Label text="C"/>
                </j:Card>
            </j:ScrollableSectionContent>
        </j:ApplicationMainContent>
    </j:ResponsiveView>
</j:initialView>
```

I don't understand why it isn't working. The above exemple show only ABC :

[image]

How to do to have inside a `j:Card` a 50px height scroll view (to show 0,1,2,3,4,5 in a scrollable content in my example) ?

I want the parent container to be ScrollableSectionContent because if I set browser windows lower than 600px I want to be able to scroll browser windows content to show `Card` content

Regards

Answer (score 1):

As Carlos said the right way I my example is to use ScrollingViewport,
Here is full working code  :

```
<j:initialView>
        <j:ResponsiveView>
            <j:ApplicationMainContent width="100%" selectedContent="ssc1">
                <j:ScrollableSectionContent name="ssc1" width="100%" >
                    <j:Card height="600" width="200">
                        <j:Label text="A"/>
                        <j:Label text="B"/>

                        <j:VGroup height="50" width="100%" gap="1">
                            <j:beads>
                                <j:ScrollingViewport/>
                            </j:beads>
                            <j:Label text="0"/>
                            <j:Label text="1"/>
                            <j:Label text="2"/>
                            <j:Label text="3"/>
                            <j:Label text="4"/>
                            <j:Label text="5"/>
                        </j:VGroup>

                        <j:Label text="C"/>
                    </j:Card>
                </j:ScrollableSectionContent>
            </j:ApplicationMainContent>
        </j:ResponsiveView>
    </j:initialView>
```

giving this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`SectionContent` (and `ScrollableSectionContent`) is not visible by default. The original purpose was to use it for navigation, so we create all and only make visible the selected one.

So you need to set `isSelected="true"` to make it visible.

Maybe we can make it visible by default and then when used in navigation container make invisible...

If you want to just have a scrollable zone, you can add one of the available containers with a `ScrollingViewport` bead.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your explanations, so I don't use the right componant. As I had some difficults to know how to use ScrollingViewport, I will post an example